# RegEx matching double quotes

Tags: c#, xml, regex, double-quotes

This pattern keeps giving me errors as if it is not backing out of the double quotes. I am trying to grab "Gen"

```
string str = "<div type=\"book\" osisID=\"Gen\">";

Match m = Regex.Match(str, @"<div type=\"book\" osisID=\"(.*?)\">", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (m.Success) {    
    Console.Write(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: Do you *really* want to parse XML/HTML with RegEx?

Comment: I just need one tag and the namespace will be changing all the time.

Comment: What are the "errors" it gives you?

Comment: The pattern isnt even being recognized as being valid

Comment: It looks like you're trying to escape quotes with `\"`. You need to escape quotes with `""` in a verbatim (`@"`) string. That said, don't use Regex to parse HTML!

Comment: @abatishchev Some people like to [live dangerously...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkzMA1jrm00)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use XML parsing mechanism to parse XML:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml)
var root = doc.Root
var osisId = root.Attribute("osisID").Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

In C# verbatim strings, you escape a quotation mark with another quotation mark, not with a backslash:

```
 @"<div type=""book"" osisID=""(.*?)"">"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have more complex html than you've just posted and have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

```
string str = "<div type=\"book\" osisID=\"Gen\">";

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(str);
var osisID = doc.DocumentNode
                .SelectSingleNode("//div[@type='book']")
                .Attributes["osisID"]
                .Value;
```

PS: [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)